# Resizing UITabBarController doesn't work in IOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, uitabbarcontroller

I have a custom UITabBarController which is presented by the main view controller and shown as a UIModalPresentationFormSheet.  The user has the option to go fullscreen and go back to a non-fullscreen view of this popup.

I have the following code which works perfectly fine in IOS7, but doesn't do anything in IOS8.

```
[self.tabBarController.view.superview setFrame:newFrame];
```

Where the "self" is a UIViewController which is the root view controller of a UINavigationController which is one of the view controllers in a UITabBarController.

I have some success with the following code

```
[self.tabBarController                  setPreferredContentSize:newFrame.size];
[self.tabBarController.view.superview   setFrame:newFrame];
[self.tabBarController.view.superview   setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[self.view                              setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
```

For whatever reason, this only works once though.  If I exit out of the view (I see dealloc being called on my UITabBarController) and then I bring up another instance of it, the fullscreen toggle does nothing.

Any help would be appreciated, I've been banging my head over this.

Comment: So you are trying to implement the UITabBarController at a custom size and position right? Check out child view controllers: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at that and I based the implementation off of that and other sources.  As I mentioned, it works fine in ios7, but breaks down in ios8. I haven't found any documentation that would explain why that could would not work with ios8 besides having to use preferredContentSize.